# Object stores incorrect values if seemingly unrelated line of code is added

Tags: javascript, es6-class, dom-events

Here's the repo: https://github.com/ZorvyY/projectiles

I've implement a Vector class and a projectile class(which is functionally just a pair of vectors). When I try to store a projectile object I've created in an array, the values of the projectile change. Here is the relevant code.

In src/Vec.js:

```
export default class Vec {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }

  // More methods...
}
```

In src/Projectile.js:

```
import Vec from './Vec.js';

class Projectile {
  constructor(position, velocity) {
    this.position = position;
    this.velocity = velocity;
  }

  // More methods...
}
```

In src/app.js:

```
import Projectile from './Projectile.js';
import Vec from './Vec.js';

let projectiles = [];

let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

function handleMouseDown(event) {
  let startX = event.offsetX;
  let startY = event.offsetY;

  function handleMouseUp(event) {
    let endX = event.offsetX;
    let endY = event.offsetY;

    let newProj = computeProjectile(startX, startY, endX, endY);
    console.log('newProj', newProj);
    canvas.removeEventListener('mouseup', handleMouseUp);
    //projectiles.push(newProj);
    //console.log(projectiles);
  }

  canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', handleMouseUp);
}

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', handleMouseDown);

function computeProjectile (x1, y1, x2, y2) {
  console.log('In computeProjectile:');
  console.log(arguments);

  let startVec = new Vec(x1, y1);
  let endVec = new Vec(x2, y2);
  let deltaVec = Vec.minus(endVec, startVec);
  let proj = new Projectile(startVec, deltaVec);

  console.log('startVec', startVec);
  console.log('endVec', endVec);
  console.log('proj', proj);

  return proj;
}
```

In the current state, each console.log statement produces the expected values. However, when I uncomment the line `projectiles.push(newProj);`, the projectile object stores nonsensical values instead of properly computed values. Keep in mind that the console.log statements are executed before `projectiles.push(newProj)`.

In other words:

```
function handleMouseDown(event) {
  let startX = event.offsetX;
  let startY = event.offsetY;

  function handleMouseUp(event) {
    let endX = event.offsetX;
    let endY = event.offsetY;

    let newProj = computeProjectile(startX, startY, endX, endY);
    console.log('newProj', newProj); //Nonsensical value if projectiles.push(newProj) is uncommented
    canvas.removeEventListener('mouseup', handleMouseUp);
    //projectiles.push(newProj);
    //console.log(projectiles);
  }

  canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', handleMouseUp);
}

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', handleMouseDown);

function computeProjectile (x1, y1, x2, y2) {
  console.log('In computeProjectile:');
  console.log(arguments);

  let startVec = new Vec(x1, y1);
  let endVec = new Vec(x2, y2);
  let deltaVec = Vec.minus(endVec, startVec);
  let proj = new Projectile(startVec, deltaVec);

  console.log('startVec', startVec); //Always produces expected value
  console.log('endVec', endVec); //Always produces expected value
  console.log('proj', proj); //Will produce a different nonsensical value than newProj if projectiles.push(newProj) is uncommented

  return proj;
}
```

even if I replace the line `let newProj = computeProjectile(startX, startY, endX, endY);` with other constants (ie `computeProjectile(12,10,50,50)`, the output of the console.log statements is different each time.

[Here's an example output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wdjG.png)

Why would storing an object in an array AFTER outputting its values change what values were outputted?

Comment: You have code [here in the `animate()` function](https://github.com/ZorvyY/projectiles/blob/master/src/app.js#L22) in your repository that is modifying the items in the `projectiles` array.  So, if you put things into the array, they will get modified by that code.

Comment: What @jfriend00 is asking is crucial. Objects are displayed in the console are *lazily*, so if you `console.log` an object, then change it, then expand the values in the console, you'll see the changed values

Comment: As @vlaz says, `console.log()` is a bit lazy (it doesn't make copies of objects and does not immediately output) so if the objects are getting changed fairly soon, `console.log()` may output the future value, not the current value.  If you want to output something immediately without the laziness, you can do `console.log(JSON.stringify(projectiles));` since `JSON.stringify()` immediately copies values into a string form at the moment you call it.

Comment: That seemed to be the issue. When commenting out animate, the values were stored correctly. I wasn't aware that console.log was lazy.